# How to add particular ids object from list using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot

This is my list which is coming in response now I have to add the objects belonging to particular itemIds using Java  ,

```
[
    {
        "data": 210,
        "dataValue":100,
        "itemIds": "60e53dee7a814f0001de3538"
    },
    {
        "data": 220,
         "dataValue":120,
        "itemIds": "60e53dee7a814f0001de3538"
    },
    {
       "data": 110,
        "dataValue":130,
        "itemIds": "60e53dee7a814f0001de3539"
    }
]
```

Ouput Required  ->

```
[
    {
        "data": 430,
         "Values":100,
        "itemIds": "60e53dee7a814f0001de3538"
    },
    {
       "data": 110,
        "dataValue":130,
        "itemIds": "60e53dee7a814f0001de3539"
    }
]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint `HashMap<K,V>` is for removing duplicate id

Comment: adding all the elements of itemIds and making in single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ListElement> elements = new ArrayList<ListElement>();
        elements.add(new ListElement(210, 100, "60e53dee7a814f0001de3538"));
        elements.add(new ListElement(220, 120, "60e53dee7a814f0001de3538"));
        elements.add(new ListElement(110, 130, "60e53dee7a814f0001de3539"));

        System.out.println(elements);

        Map<String, List<ListElement>> elementsByItemId = elements.stream() //
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ListElement::getItemId)); //

        elements = elementsByItemId.entrySet().stream() //
                .map(entry -> new ListElement( //
                        entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(ListElement::getData)), //
                        entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(ListElement::getDataValue)), //
                        entry.getKey())) //
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(elements);
    }

    int data;
    int dataValue;
    String itemId;

    public ListElement(int data, int dataValue, String itemId) {
        this.data = data;
        this.dataValue = dataValue;
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getDataValue() {
        return dataValue;
    }

    public void setDataValue(int dataValue) {
        this.dataValue = dataValue;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListElement [data=" + data + ", dataValue=" + dataValue + ", itemId=" + itemId + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what If I dont want to add the particulaar element in the list , can u pls help with that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to filter elements out of the stream?

https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-filter-lambda

Comment: then you may use the .filter method

f.e.:
elements.stream().filter(element -> element.getData() > 200)

Comment: I have just updated the question , can u pls check that once , I dont want to change the value of values in that case what should be done , can u pls help

Comment: Are the values of the items with the same itemId always the same? If not what should happen if they differ?

Comment: I have added another question pls check that and help me with that scenario , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294372/how-to-do-add-and-subtract-elements-from-particular-object-in-list-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a not perfect example of how to do this. Maybe you can improve this solution to your liking. For simplicity it uses an inner class and exposed fields. I'm sure you will avoid doing this :)
It uses a custom aggregating operator and the reduce method of streams (see [java stream reduce tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) or [java stream reduce doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html))

```
private static BinaryOperator<Item> itemAggregator = (aggregatedResult, nextElement) -> {
    aggregatedResult.data += nextElement.data;
    aggregatedResult.dataValue += nextElement.dataValue;
    return aggregatedResult;
};

public static void something(List<Item> initialItemList) {
    Set<String> uniqueItemIds = initialItemList.stream()
            .map(item -> item.itemId)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    List<Item> resultList = uniqueItemIds.stream()
            .map(itemId -> new Item(0, 0, itemId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    resultList.forEach(
            resultItem -> {
                initialItemList.stream()
                        .filter(item -> item.itemId.equals(resultItem.itemId))
                        .reduce(resultItem, itemAggregator);
    });
}

static class Item {
    public int data;
    public int dataValue;
    public String itemId;

    public Item(int data, int dataValue, String itemId) {
        this.data = data;
        this.dataValue = dataValue;
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
}
```

But be aware, that using the reduce method can easily be done wrong (see [avoid reduce if possible](https://dev.java/learn/adding-a-terminal-operation-on-a-stream/)) and you have to check if it makes sense in your context.